# Android apps that share data : Failed to find provider null for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority

Tags: android, sqlite, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

I have **App A** that shares its database with **App B** with a help of a `ContentProvider`.

Both Apps have Sdk Version 28 in the gradle.

**The manifest of App A**

```
    <permission android:name="com.example.mldemo.READ_DATABASE" android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.mldemo.WRITE_DATABASE" android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    ....
    <application 
       ...
       <provider android:name=".content_providers.MLProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.mldemo"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:readPermission="com.example.mldemo.READ_DATABASE"
            android:writePermission="com.example.mldemo.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
```

**The manifest of App B**

```
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mldemo.READ_DATABASE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mldemo.WRITE_DATABASE" />
```

**App B** consumes the **`ContentProvider`** like this :

```
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.mldemo";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/");
    .... 
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + "/CONTACTS");
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put("NAME", contact.getName());
    ...
    newUri = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(
                uri,
                newValues
        );
```

When I `QUERY` the `contentProvider`, it works fine.
The problem happens when I `insert`. I keep having this error :

```
Failed to find provider null for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
When doing an insert in the ContentProvider, you need to pass the authority when calling notifyChange :

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/");
...
Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + TABLE_NAME), newId);
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
```